# How to declare annotation processor witch is inside of gradle module

Tags: android, gradle, annotation-processor

I have modules in my Android project. One of modules (moduleA for example) use another (moduleB) as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':moduleB')
}
```

And also I still have apt and old gradle plagin. Now, I delete apt from gradle files, upgrade plugin version and get error:

```
Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following 
dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation 
processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
  - moduleB.jar (project :moduleB)
```

If we use some external dependency we do like this (for example) to resolve this problem:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
```

But what I need to do with my case, when annotattion processor is inside of gradle module? Could you explain it, because I don't have deep understanding in this area and usually I simply take this lines

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
```

from repository of library provider. I try to research this case, but don't find anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project(':moduleB')` is just a way to specify an inter-project dependencies, like you do with "full" coordinates (`com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8`). So, to use another module as an annotation processor just use

```
dependencies {
    …
    annotationProcessor(project(":moduleB"))
    …
}
```